# If $E[h(M_n)]\to h(x)$ for all bounded and continuous functions $h$ then $M_n\to x$ in probability

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $M_n$ be a sequence of random variables and let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\mathbb{E}[h(M_n)]\to h(x)$$
as $n\to\infty$ for all bounded and continuous functions $h$.

> How to show that for all $\delta>0$ we have $\mathbb{P}(|M_n-x|>\delta)\to0$?

What I thought:
Convergence of $\mathbb{E}[h(M_n)]$ means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\geq0$ such that $\mathbb{E}[h(M_n)-h(x)]<\epsilon$.
Further we hav $\mathbb{P}(|M_n-x|>\delta)=\mathbb{E}[1_{|M_n-x|>\delta}]$, however the indicator function is not continuous. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stated assumption [implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) that $M_n\xrightarrow{d}x$ and, [thus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution_to_a_constant_implies_convergence_in_probability), $M_n\xrightarrow{p} x$.

---

*Direct proof*. For any $\delta>0$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|M_n-x|>\delta)&=\mathsf{P}(M_n>x+\delta)+\mathsf{P}(M_n<x-\delta) \\
&\le 1+\mathsf{E}h_{\delta}(M_n-x)-\mathsf{E}h_{\delta}(M_n+\delta-x),\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $h_\delta(v):=1\wedge(0\vee v/\delta)$. Since $h_{\delta}$ is a continuous bounded function, $(1)$ converges to
$$
1+h_{\delta}(0)-h_{\delta}(\delta)=0.
$$

Comment: But I do not want to use convergence in distribution, I would prefer to prove this without using the implications you give, i.e. without the portmanteau lemma